# Get a notification when a timer is created by Google Home

Tags: google-home

Is there any way to get a notification in my application when I set a timer (such as "5 minutes") by voice with Google Home?

I wish I could display the countdown time using an ESP microcontroller and a segmented display. Displaying countdown is easy, but I don't know if it is possible to programmatically know when a timer has started.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a Smart Home Action, you can use the `Timer` [trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/timer), which will enable you to query by voice how much time is left, as long as you set the `commandOnlyTimer` attribue to false (this allows querying and reporting the device state).

Your [execute response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#handle_execute_intents) can then also include the status of `SUCCESS` or any `ERROR` codes that may occur when setting the timer.